# Unity ads in flutter via admob mediation

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine, admob

In my **flutter app** , `admob` ads are already showing , I want to show unity ads via `admob` mediation.

How to setup unity ads in flutter app via admob mediation?

Answer (score 0):

There is [official doc](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/mediation/unity) from google admobs that very much explains the Unity Ads integration using mediation.
There are several tutorial videos on youtube aswell. Please try the steps and asks specifically if you face issue in any of those steps or if any step is confusing.
eg. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnr4mlVctXw

A generic guide for mediation in Flutter is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/mediation/get-started).

Also, it is noteworthy that the dependencies  need to be added in android gradle file and ios Podfile separately as mentioned here: *[Add dependencies for partner networks](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/mediation/get-started#add_dependencies_for_partner_networks)*